# What's wrong with my formula? Just want to show the correct days left

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

I am trying to determine what is wrong with my formula. Just want to show the correct days left.

```
Exp. Date = RSPOExpDate
```

Using Domino Designer 8.

[image: Please see screenshot]

```
temp := ((RSPOExpDate - @Today)/60)/60;
tempdays := @TextToNumber(temp)/24;
days := @Left(@Text(tempdays); ".");
@If(days = @Text(days));
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKV5W.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't** include in your view selection formula or column formulas any function which delivers current time or date like **@Now** or **@Today** for performance reasons. Those functions cause the view to refresh every time it is called.

In case you want to stay with it then change your formula to

```
@Integer((RSPOExpDate - @Today)/60/60/24)
```

In case RSPOExpDate can be empty use this

```
@If(RSPOExpDate = ""; ""; @Integer((RSPOExpDate - @Today)/60/60/24))
```

*Update:*

Write an agent that runs sometime in first hours of every day with the formula:

```
FIELD DaysLeft := @If(RSPOExpDate = ""; ""; @Integer((RSPOExpDate - @Today)/60/60/24))
```

Your column formula is then just

```
DaysLeft
```

or you show a red/green flag icon

```
@If((DaysLeft)<=90; 181; 182)
```

Comment: Hi Knut, thanks for the answer. so only the 1st line will be changed? Same result.

Comment: No, use just this one code line. That is the whole code you need.

Comment: Hi Knut, if you dont mind, what if I just want to show in the column the expiring in 3 months and will use "Display values as icons". Like if the rem. days is less than 3months or 90 days? the icon will be red and if not its green. Will it lessen the performance issue?

Comment: Hi Knut, how do I know or create a field name for Days Left? Formula: @If((DaysLeft)<=90; 181 ;182)

Comment: Thanks for the answers Knut, sorry for asking too many. but is there a way that will not create an agent? just write the formula and replace 89 (sample value) that will get the value from the Days Left column. How do I create or find the Field Name for Days Left column? Added screenshot above.

Comment: This would work, but it has the heavy performance issues because of @Today: `@If(RSPOExpDate = ""; ""; @Integer((RSPOExpDate - @Today)/60/60/24)) <= 90; 181; 182)`. So, don't be afraid to create an agent :) - it would be the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Knut! Now that I have right results and overview, I will now try to move this to agent. It will be a challenge to me but I'll still try. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in your last line.  Just set it to `days`.  That will return the calculated number of days remaining (or days passed as it will show a negative for that).

As Knut says, the performance for this will be pretty poor.  It would be much better for performance to have an agent that runs nightly to stamp the number of days remaining on the document and show this field in that column.  You can use the same formula as you have and just replace the last line with `@SetField("DaysRemianing"; days);`at the end of the formula

Answer (score 0):

The Agent based approach already outlined is correct.  Consider using @BusinessDays to make life easier.

```
 @BusinessDays(startDates; endDates; daysToExclude; datesToExclude)
```

Something like:

```
@BusinessDays(RSPOExpDate; @Today)
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_BUSINESSDAYS_FUNCTION.html